# Python re.search Patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a bunch of strings that consist of Q, D or T. Below are some examples.

```
              aa= "QDDDDQDTDQTD"
              bb = "QDT"
              cc = "TDQDQQDTQDQ"
```

i am new to re.search, for each string, is it possible to get all patterns with any length that start with Q, and ends with D or Q, and there is no T in between the first Q and the last D or Q.

So for aa, it would find "QDDDDQD"

for bb, it would find "QD"

for cc, it would find "QDQQD" and "QDQ"

I understand the basic forms of using re.search like:

```
              re.search(pattern, my_string, flags=0)
```

Just having trouble how to set up the patterns mentioned above, like how to find patterns start with Q, or ends with Q, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern that follows what you describe: start with `Q`, then anything but T with `[^T]*`, then D or Q with `[DQ]`:

```
>>> import re
>>> aa = "QDDDDQDTDQTD"
>>> bb = "QDT"
>>> cc = "TDQDQQDTQDQ"
>>> print(*(re.findall(r'Q[^T]*[DQ]', st) for st in (aa,bb,cc)), sep='\n')
['QDDDDQD']
['QD']
['QDQQD', 'QDQ']
```

Comment: thx! thats exactly what i want!

Answer (score 4):

A pattern you that works is `Q[DQ]+`. That is: starts with "Q", followed by several "D" or "Q".

However, if you want to *find* *all* matches, you need [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), not [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
In [9]: re.findall('Q[DQ]+', aa)
Out[9]: ['QDDDDQD']

In [10]: re.findall('Q[DQ]+', bb)
Out[10]: ['QD']

In [11]: re.findall('Q[DQ]+', cc)
Out[11]: ['QDQQD', 'QDQ']

In [12]:
```

Comment: thx! just want to make sure that [DQ] means D or Q, and therefore [DT] means D or T? thx for the help!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: thx for the heads up!